# Add 'Reply Now' button in email body

Tags: php, email, html-email

I want to add CTA button 'Reply Now' in my email body. How can we achieve this? It should behave similarly like Gmail 'Reply' button or any other email reply button.

Ex:

```
.....
If you want to know more ...
 [REPLY NOW]

Regards,
******
```

Comment: Uhm. You want the Call To Action button to refer to the mailclient reply-functionality or do you want it to refer to a page with a reply form on your site? The first is not possible AFAIK (because the mailclient the receiver of the mail uses could be literally anything), the second is possible by sending an html-mail inserting a button with a href...

Comment: I'm looking for the first option. The user can reply to the same email thread by clicking on the 'reply' button. Can we add a script for Gmail and outlook?

Comment: Hi @stefun, I don't know about Hotmail, but Gmail adds those buttons and standard "Smart Replies" by themselves and dynamically. It cannot be influenced by senders. Plus if you're targeting multinationally, I'm not sure if it's been rolled out in all countries. Plus, this functionality can be switched off by the user...

Answer (score -1):

This will send an email in html format containing some sample text and a slightly styled button. Adjust and add content to your needs and likings...

```
 $mailTo       = "mail@receiverdomain.com";
 $mailSubject  = "Testmail with a styled button.";
 $mailHeaders  = "From: no-reply@yourdomain.com\r\n";
 $mailHeaders .= "Reply-To: no-reply@yourdomain.com\r\'n";
 $mailHeaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
 $mailHeaders .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
 $mailContent  = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><style>button {background-color: lightblue;}</style></head><body>';
 $mailContent .= '<h1>Hi! This is sample content</h1><p>This is a sample paragraph.</p><a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com/"><button>Go to Stackoverflow!</button></a>';
 $mailContent .= '</body></html>';

 mail($mailTo, $mailSubject, $mailContent, $mailHeaders);
```